# quadlet podman container with macvlan, how to configure mac address?

Tags: systemd, mac-address, podman, macvlan

I am using the new quadlet to automatically start podman container, getting its ip from the dhcp server using the following systemd config:

`adguard.container`

```
[Unit]
Description=Adguard Container

[Container]
Image=docker.io/adguard/adguardhome:latest
AutoUpdate=registry
ContainerName=AdguardHome
HostName=adguard
Volume=/opt/adguardhome/conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf
Volume=/opt/adguardhome/work:/opt/adguardhome/work
Network=adguard.network

[Service]
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and

`adguard.network`

```
[Unit]
Description=Adguard network

[Network]
NetworkName=adguard-network
Driver=macvlan
Options=parent=enu1u1
Subnet=172.16.0.0/24
IPRange=172.16.0.1/25
Gateway=172.16.0.1
```

It is working fine.

The problem is that the mac address is not fixed after each startup and I cannot assign the same ip to the container using my dhcp server.

How to fix this macvlan container mac address?

In podman-compose (docker-compose), it is possible to do it with https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#mac_address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PodmanArgs=--mac-address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc` to set extra options that aren't [valid podman unit keys (as per the manpage)](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-systemd.unit.5.html).
`PodmanArgs` can be specified multiple times and you probably also want `--replace` to avoid conflicts.

You can also specify (network) driver options if you need something like `Options=isolate=true`.

You can also dry run the quadlet generator to check for errors (like putting values in wrong unit file type):
`/usr/libexec/podman/quadlet -dryrun` (+ `-user` for rootless) 
It will display the complete `ExecStart` line for your podman command.